# Glyphicon and Text Simulatenous Color Change on Hover

Tags: css, hover, glyphicons

I am having difficulties achieving this with CSS techniques.
Maybe I am missing something, but I thought to ask here before I look into Jquery options.

```
.glyphicon:hover {
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.60);
}
```

works to change the glyphicon color on hover.

```
.h2footer a:hover {
        color: white;
}
```

Works to change the text element color below it on hover.

But I am trying to achieve to whereas if you hover over the glyphicon the color of the glyphicon AND the text below it both change color.

Meaning, per the example below, if you hover over the forms glyphicon, that changes color, but so does the text below it that says 'Forms'.

https://jsfiddle.net/534gynwv/

Comment: This link may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not:

```
<div class="col-md-4 double-highlight">
    <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar marketing"></i></a>
    <h2 class="h2footer"><a href="#">Schedule an<br> Appointment</a></h2>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

And:

```
.double-highlight:hover .glyphicon, .double-highlight:hover .h2footer a{ color:white; }
```

Comment: but this will apply hovering effects also outside icon and text. when hover in any area in double-highlight div

Comment: Yes. And a potential solution around that would be to wrap both elements in your `<a>` tag and give it the class double-highlight.

Comment: Wow very good.  Wasn't expecting a one-line solution.  But what do you mean by 'give it to the class double-highlight'?  I've done this `<div class="col-md-4 double-highlight">
            <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope marketing"></i>
            <h2 class="h2footer double-highlight">Contact</a></h2>` but it still highlighting outside?

Comment: I mean `a href="#" class="double-highlight"` still highlights everything if the div has the class of double-highlight

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? See updated html/css: https://jsfiddle.net/534gynwv/1/

Comment: That works.  Perfect.  Thank you.  For some reason it was not working for me on my live site... I believe I had some extra <div>'s that shouldn't of been there or something.  All good though!